# Detect words or any character after some match pattern, Regex Pattern (Vim)

Tags: regex, vim

I have a text file patterned like this :

```
1 textA == this is textA ==
1.1 textB === this is textB ===
2 textC == this is textC ==
2.1 textD === this is textD ===
2.1.1 textE ==== this is textE ====
```

Whats the right regex pattern to formatting the text above:

```
== this is textA ==
=== this is textB ===
== this is textC ==
=== this is textD ===
```

I already try to perfoming this in vim :

```
^\w* -> this pattern just changes only textA and textB
```

I need to detect "." and any character or words until meet the "=" sign. Any characters behind the "=" sign will be deleted. Thanks in advance for any answers and pointers.

---

**Solution**

```
^.\{-}\ze=
```

**Explanation :**

```
^.   -> started with any single character
\{-} -> matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible
\ze= -> Matches at any position, and sets the end of the match there: The previous char  is the last char of the whole match
```

In human words :
 
"Find and replace a text started with any single character followed by anything and ended with "=" sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:%s/^.\{-}\ze=//
```

For more details on how to design reg.exps in Vim, see `:help pattern` which is the most useful section help in Vim IMHO.

`:help :g` and `:help :v` could also be of interest to you. You could for example do:

```
:g/=/normal! 0dt=
```

which will emulate you typing 0dt= on each line containing an = sign.

Comment: Hello. ^ is start of line, .\{-} is as few characters as possible, \ze is END OF MATCHED SECTION and = is another character that is to be present afterwards, but which will not count as matched.